# Why I can't install postgresql with rails 4.0.0.rc1 (ruby 2.0)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, compiler-errors, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

first time on forum so i will try to be as specific as one can be, sorry for any possible typos ok?

I am relatively new to rails (less than a year), and i want to make a default project to work with it. I have always used sqlite3 in development and pg in production (heroku), but now i want to make things right (i've encountered problems with sqlite3 running ok but pg not) and use both pg in production and devlop.

I have spent 2 days searching foruns and all the anwsers are old or other versions/other OS.

I'll try to list the steps i took for setting up my stage:
Here my configs:

-OS: Windows 7 64x
-Editor: Aptana Studio
-PostGresql
-Rails 4.0.0.rc1
-Ruby 2.0

1. Download and Install postgresql-9.2.4-1-windows-x64
2. Set a default Password to postgresql
3. Create an Role "my_user" in postgresql with all privilegies
4. Create an testing database "rails_test"
5. Open Aptana Studio and init an new default project going to the project folder and than running "rails new . -d postgresql" for generate the new project.
6. Install the pg gem "gem install pg" "gem list" shows the pg gem correctly
7. configure "database.yml" for using the correct username and password

   ```
   development:
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     database: rails_test
     pool: 5
     username: my_user
     password: 12345
   ```
8. Running some commands in ruby like "gem update", "bundle install"

then when i try to generate an model and use rake db:migrate i get the following error:

```
    Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
```

and it's true if i run "bundle show pg" i get the message:

```
    Could not find gem 'pg'. Did you mean pg?
```

If i open my gemfile the pg gem is there, but the bundler is not getting it !

Any ideias to help this little amateur?

TNX !

Comment: try just `bundle` instead of `bundle install`  My guess is that pg is not in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: i tryed bundle...same effect! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it by using the 32bit version of ruby rather than the 64bit. You need to make sure the devkit matches up to your version as well. So if you have the 64 bit version of that installed then that will need to be changed too.

Comment: i hope that there's another way to do it! i'd like to use

Comment: I agree it is not really a great answer. I tried a lot of things. You can open your gemlock and find the pg version. You could try making sure that is the x64 version and then gem uninstall pg and run bundle install again. It didn't work for me but it is worth a try.

Comment: JimmyT I searched again in my gemfile.lock and the gem appears to be in 32 bits (pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)) which is possibly causing the problem. So it reallys worth the try ! tnx !

Comment: omg my Gem list has the 64x version. Now the thing is how to make rails/bundle use the 64x version of the gem pg. But my bundler refuses to "see the gem"

Comment: That is where I got stuck, I couldn't figure out what was letting me down. Thinking back I had other gems that behaved weirdly with the 64 bit version of ruby installer. Like you I spent a couple of days on it but decided that for my dev environment having a more stable 32 bit environment was worth it so I could just get back to programming. I guess this is just one of the pains of developing on windows os.

Comment: I spent several hours on this... Your answer is spot on. Seems like a good solution for those of us who develop on Windows but still deploy to Linux for production.

Answer (score 6):

(Windows 7 x64, Ruby2.0.0p247-x64, Rails4.0.0, Postgresql 9.2.4 x64, pg 0.15.1, mysql2 0.3.11) 
There seems to be a platform detection/verification problem with bundler.  While what I did *is* a hack of the Gemfile.lock file (I know, I know...), I have a (hopefully) temporary solution:

Edit Gemfile.lock, and

- Find the line for 'pg':

> ```
>  multi_json (1.7.7)
>  pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)
>  polyglot (0.3.3)
> ```

- Copy the line, and modify the new copy to :

> ```
>  multi_json (1.7.7)
>  pg (0.15.1-x64-mingw32)
>  pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)
>  polyglot (0.3.3)
> ```

This is how the x64 version of the installed gem announces itself when you ask to list it (`gem list pg`).

For anyone who cares, the *exact* same problem was (sometimes) encountered with the mysql2 gem.

Comment: yeah, worked for me too. not the nicest one, but it's better than switching everything to x32, supposing this is a temporary issue ...

Comment: I can confirm this problem is solved by merely replacing the line with `pg(0.xx.1)-x64-ming32). xx as in whatever version number you have it seems. 

I had to do this today once I upgraded to Ruby 2.0 64-bit w/ Rails 4 after the dependency bugs involving bcrypt and the atomic gems that prevented me in the past being able to do so was resolved.

PG version 0.17.0 if that helps anyone.