# Can't run rails in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I use this command to access rails console environment:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

However it return a stack trace tell me to add gem 'pg' to my Gemfile. I already have 'pg' from scratch, do you any advise ? I have just switch to learn Ruby for a while.

```
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
...
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

source :rubygems
gem 'rack'
```

the console logs when i run `bundle install`

```
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' i
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.1)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.1)
Using mime-types (1.25)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.1)
Using activemodel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.1)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.1)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.0)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.1)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass (3.2.12)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
Using uglifier (2.3.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Could you show us the content of your Gemfile?

Comment: I added the file.I Tried "bundle install"  many times, but nothing happen

Comment: try adding 
`gem "pg", "~> 0.17.0"` or run `gem install pg`

Comment: Yeah postgres was installed.

Comment: If you are on Windows 7 64-bit, try the workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17725326/2622934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `pg (0.17.0-x64-mingw32)` to Gemfile.lock so it's ok now. Thanks all.